# Push/upload files in Heroku cloud using Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, heroku

I have a few csv, jpg and png files in my local computer.

I need to upload/push these files to Heroku cloud platform using Python.

Can somebody please let me know how do we go about doing this in Python?

Comment: Heroku is for hosting **applications**. It is not clear what you want to do with "upload/push files to Heroku". You need to create an app, deploy that app to Heroku, then maybe upload files to your app. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/python-support

Comment: Hi @GinoMempin..From a loal computer-1, I wish to upload them in my heroku account (Just like we use google cloud services). and then later on, I shall download those files in another local computer-2.

Comment: Then it sounds like what you need is a file-sharing service like Google Drive or Dropbox, most of which have Python APIs. Or maybe a git repository like Github or Bitbucket, which also have Python APIs. As I said, Heroku is for hosting applications, not for file-sharing.

Comment: See also [Why are my file uploads missing/deleted?](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) from Heroku docs, on why Heroku cannot be used as a file-storage/file-sharing platform.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GinoMempin for your feedback. I can now understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

You can push something to Heroku using git push from your git-shell. If you want to upload files or something to Heroku then you create an app from given stacks of Heroku. Then place these files in that app and then push them to Heroku.
As per my knowledge, you can directly upload images to a new Heroku dyno as builds will famil automatically.

Comment: Even if they get an app running for uploading files, Heroku dynos are ephemeral, the files will get deleted when the dynos restart (even for non-free tier). See [Why are my file uploads missing/deleted?](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted). They will have to put their files *somewhere else*, so it's better to just use that *somewhere else* directly than use Heroku. [From the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65964679/push-upload-files-in-heroku-cloud-using-python#comment116630720_65964679), what they seem to need is a file-sharing service.

Comment: If your files are included in the code repo that is committed and hosted as an app then your files will not get deleted. If you later upload some files via app uploading or some source then the file will go missing for sure.